# Switch TENS unit between many channels

Tags: multiplexer, high-voltage

I would like to switch the output of a tens unit (one of those things that uses electricity for pain relief) to 8+ different outputs. I want to create an electro tactile device. The idea is to switch the output of each lead from the tens device to 8 different channels. The channels would output to points held against the skin. Much like an lcd screen, each pair of outputs from the two sets of 8 channels would address an individual electrotactile pixel. I would probably want to be switching at ~1000hz. I've been looking at analogue multiplexers and switches, but they all seem to be limited to vcc from the microcontroller side. The tens device has a max voltage output of 7.3Vrms and a max current of 13.6mArms. Max frequency output is 150hz.

Perhaps at the low settings I want to be using the tens unit I don't have to worry about the vcc limit (5v)? If I take this approach how do I connect the two devices togethor, is it enough to connect the grounds?

Comment: TENS units typically have output in 30-60V range. They are powered by 9V batteries but typically have a step-up transformer at the output. Anything less would not cause enough current to activate nerves through the skin.

Answer (score 3):

> *I would like to switch the output of a tens unit to 8+ different outputs.*
>
> "*Max frequency output is 150 Hz.*"
>
> "*I would probably want to be switching at ~1000 Hz.*"

Something is not right here. It seems to me that you think you can use one TENS machine to do the job of eight+ by switching fast enough. I can see a few problems:

- You will no longer be applying a 150 Hz signal to the skin. You will be applying a 1 kHz signal modulated at 150 Hz.
- The average current will fall to 1/8 of the current in correct use (if everything else goes well).
- The TENS unit is probably running a constant current generator circuit. Rapid switching of the load will probably cause havoc with the internal regulation.

Note: SI Units named after a person are capitalised when abreviated and lower-case when spelled out. "V" for volt, "Hz" for hertz, etc.

Comment: The current will be 64* less, since there are 8*8 skin contact points. But this shouldn't be an issue because the contact points are much smaller, you need much less current to illicit a sensation. I hadn't realised that, yup, I will be putting out a 1khz superimposed with a 150hz signal. But I'm not sure this will be a problem, I bet that it will still cause a sensation. I am however slightly concerned about your last point and current limiting. If the switching causes it to fail it *might* be possible to cause nerve damage. Do you have any thoughts on how to approach the problem differently?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I did read a question here some months ago about, I think, a tactile glove or trying to sense human fingers closing but I can't remember enough to find it.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the time. You have made me realise this needs more thought and a more considered approach. I just wanted a quick proof of principle prototype before investing more time, but I see now that it's unwise.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to update. You've had the 1% inspiration and now you're into the 99% perspiration stage. :^)